# Controlling another application from within tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know if what I'm seeking to achieve is even possible. I have written a tkinter app which imports a method from an external class. This method runs a hill-climbing algorithm which will run perpetually and try to improve upon the "score" that it has calculated. After each pass, it presents the current output and score to the user and asks (on the command line) if they wish to continue.

The first challenge in getting this working was to implement threading. I have this working, but I don't don't know if I have done it correctly.

The algorithm will continue until the user signals that they have got the answer they were looking for, or loses the will to live and presses CTRL-C.

In my tkinter main app, this presents me with two problems:

1. How to display the output from this external method. I tried to write a while loop that polled the output field periodically, (see commented out section of the "start_proc" method) but that was clearly never going to work, and besides, I would ideally like to see real-time output; and
2. How to interact with the algorithm to either continue or stop (see commented out section of the "my_long_procedure" method). As you can see, I can inject a "stopped" attribute, and that does indeed halt the algorithm, but I can't take my eyes off the output because the desired answer may have gone past before I can press stop.

Below is, I hope, a simplified bare-bones example of what I am trying to do.

This is a learning exercise for me and I would be grateful of any help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
import time

class MyTestClass: # This would actually be imported from another module
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopped = False

    def my_long_procedure(self):
        # Fake method to simulate actual algorithm
        count = 0
        maxscore = 0
        i = 0
        while count < 1000 and not self.stopped:
            i += 1
            score = randint(1,10000)
            if score > maxscore:
                maxscore = score
                self.message = f'This is iteration {i} and the best score is {maxscore}'
                print(self.message)
                # self.carry_on = input("Do you want to continue? ")
                # if self.carry_on.upper() != "Y":
                #     return maxscore
            time.sleep(2)
        print('OK - You stopped me...')

class MyMainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title="Sample App", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.test_run = MyTestClass()
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="My Frame")
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        start_button = tk.Button(self.frame1, text="Start!",
                                command=self.start_proc).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        stop_button = tk.Button(self.frame1, text="Stop!",
                                command=self.stop_proc).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)
        self.output_box = tk.Text(self.frame1, width=60, height=8, wrap=tk.WORD)
        self.output_box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def start_proc(self):
        self.test_run.stopped = False
        self.control_thread = Thread(target=self.test_run.my_long_procedure, daemon=True)
        self.control_thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.output_box.delete(0.0, tk.END)
        self.output_box.insert(0.0, self.test_run.message)
        # self.control_thread.join()
        # while not self.test_run.stopped:
        #     self.output_box.delete(0.0, tk.END)
        #     self.output_box.insert(0.0, self.test_run.message)
        #     time.sleep(0.5)

    def stop_proc(self):
        self.test_run.stopped = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp("My Test App").mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the implementation of the algorithm you could pass a callback (a method of `MyMainApp`) so that the algorithm signals on his own whenever he has done some "work" worth notification to the user. This would look like:

```
def my_long_procedure(self,progress):
```

The callback prototype could be:

```
 def progress(self,iteration,result):
```

and instead of `print(self.message)` you could do `progress(i,maxscore)`

starting the thread:

```
self.control_thread = Thread(target=self.test_run.my_long_procedure, daemon=True,args=(self.progress,))
```

Unfortunatly you need to be aware that you cannot refresh the GUI from another thread than the main thread. This is a much discussed tkinter limitation. So in a nutshell you cannot directly call any of your GUI widgets from `progress` function. The workaround to this issue is to store the progress in the progress function and register a function to be executed whenever the tkinter main loop will be idle. you can do somethink like `self.after_idle(self.update_ui)` from `progress` method. `update_ui()` would be a new methode updating eg a progress bar or your graph using data transmitted by the `progress` callback and saved as `MyMainApp` properties.
More on this "pattern" (using message queues instead of callback) here:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch09s07.html

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Marc Volle. I very much appreciate your help. I think I follw what you are trying to do, I haven't quite got it to work yet however. Currently it gives me an error: `TypeError: my_long_procedure() argument after * must be an iterable, not method`. Also, whilst this (when I get it working) should solve problem no. 1, I am not sure it can help with problem no. 2 (or can it?) Thanks again though. I am grateful for your help.

Comment: OK - I fixed it by using the command `self.control_thread = Thread(target=lambda :self.test_run.my_long_procedure(self.progress), daemon=True)`. Thanks! That certainly solves problem number 1! Now, can I use this approach to solve problem number 2? Thanks again!

Comment: Hello. Sorry the error was due to the fact a coma is needed when creating a 1 element tupple `args=(self.progress,)` I fixed my porposal. I'm not sure I understood what you mean by *but I can't take my eyes off the output because the desired answer may have gone past before I can press stop*. Do you need some kind of historization of the results so that you can "revert" to one already displayed and gone the time you stop the algo?

Comment: Thanks! - I had also worked out the missing comma from the tuple as well (just after I used the lambda technique).

Comment: What I mean about the output is that the nature of the algorithm is that it uses a randomisation technique that means that the optimal answer may appear in the output, but then the next pass may produce a less good answer. Pausing the output by asking for input to a "do you want to continue" question means that the user can decide to stop the algorithm when they see the optimal answer. That said, given the scoring mechanism, it is actually quite unlikely (but not impossible) that a worse answer will appear after a good one. But, if possible, I would like to mirror the pause for confirmation...

Comment: ... mechanism of the CLI version. If this is not possible I think I can live with just hoping that the last output will generally be the best answer.

Comment: Hello. OK So now I understand you want to run the next iteration of the algo only once the user confirms he want to try another round. It is completly different than updating regularly the user of the current progress. Next iteration shall be triggered by the user. In that case you could reuse the above pattern but have the UI maintain an execution context of the algorithm and pass it at each call to `my_long_procedure` (if context requires to be maintained between to runs (like eg simulated annealing optimizations). context would also have to become an parameter of `progress` callback.